mysqldump.exe: Got error: 2004: "Can't create TCP/IP socket (10106)" when trying to connect (Laravel 10)
tengo el siguiente problema, al querer descargar o hacer el respaldo de una base de datos con un archivo .sql desde react + js a laravel 10 para que este se encargue de procesar la petición.
Equipo: Hp envy, Windows 11.
La cuestión es que al hacer uno de esos 2 procesos en el laravel.log me da el siguiente error:
[2024-11-07 20:34:30] local.ERROR: The command "C:\xampp\mysql\bin\mysqldump.exe --user=root --password= --host=127.0.0.1 heart_2_health "--result-file=C:\Users\Victor\Desktop\Heart_2_Health_deni\Heart_2_Health\storage\app/backup_2024_11_07_203430.sql"" failed.

Exit Code: 2(Misuse of shell builtins)

Working directory: C:\Users\Victor\Desktop\Heart_2_Health_deni\Heart_2_Health\public

Output:
================


Error Output:
================
mysqldump.exe: Got error: 2004: "Can't create TCP/IP socket (10106)" when trying to connect
 {"userId":1,"exception":"[object] (Symfony\\Component\\Process\\Exception\\ProcessFailedException(code: 0): The command \"C:\\xampp\\mysql\\bin\\mysqldump.exe --user=root --password= --host=127.0.0.1 heart_2_health \"--result-file=C:\\Users\\Victor\\Desktop\\Heart_2_Health_deni\\Heart_2_Health\\storage\\app/backup_2024_11_07_203430.sql\"\" failed.

Exit Code: 2(Misuse of shell builtins)

Working directory: C:\\Users\\Victor\\Desktop\\Heart_2_Health_deni\\Heart_2_Health\\public

Output:
================


Error Output:
================
mysqldump.exe: Got error: 2004: \"Can't create TCP/IP socket (10106)\" when trying to connect

 at C:\\Users\\Victor\\Desktop\\Heart_2_Health_deni\\Heart_2_Health\\app\\Http\\Controllers\\BackupController.php:53)


Cuando recién logré que funcionara tanto el respaldo y restauración todo iba bien sin problemas, guarde el proyecto, termine las sesiones del servidor en cmd y listo, pasaron 2 o 3 horas y volví a probar el proyecto me tope con este problema el cual no he encontrado como resolverlo, desde ese momento he podido hacer la restauracion y el respaldo nunca mas.
Lo curioso radica en que cuando comparto el código con mi colega, él no tiene ningún fallo, le permite descargar y restaurar la base de datos; Puede apagar el laptop y encenderlo y probar de nuevo y sin problemas.
será que es problema del servidor de laravel, lo estoy ejecutando con: php artisan serve, o me hará falta correr algún comando para que esto funcione correctamente???
Cabe aclarar que tengo diferentes rutas para CRUDS las cuales funcionan correctamente, solo tengo problema al hacer estas operaciones.
Quiero aclarar también que los comando para respaldo (mysqldump) y restauración (mysql) están funcionando correctamente en el símbolo del sistema CMD.
La base de datos se ejecuta con el servidor de aplicaciones Xampp.
rutas:
Route::get('/backup', [BackupController::class, 'downloadBackup']);
Route::post('/uploadSQL', [RestoreController::class, 'restoreBackup']);

Ejmplo de BackupContoller.php:
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Response;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Storage;
use Symfony\Component\Process\Exception\ProcessFailedException;
use Symfony\Component\Process\Process;
use Dotenv\Dotenv;


class BackupController extends Controller
{

    public function __construct()
    {
        $dotenv = Dotenv::createImmutable(base_path());
        $dotenv->load();
    }

    public function downloadBackup()
    {
        // Definir el nombre del archivo de respaldo
        $fileName = 'backup_' . now()->format('Y_m_d_His') . '.sql';

        // Ruta donde se guardará temporalmente el archivo de respaldo
        $backupPath = storage_path("app/{$fileName}");

        // Comando de mysqldump para crear el respaldo
        $process = new Process([
            'C:\xampp\mysql\bin\mysqldump.exe',
            '--user=' . env('DB_USERNAME'),
            '--password=' . env('DB_PASSWORD'),
            '--host=' . env('DB_HOST'),
            env('DB_DATABASE'),
            '--result-file=' . $backupPath,
        ]);


        // Ejecutar el comando
        $process->run();

        // Verificar si el comando fue exitoso
        if (!$process->isSuccessful()) {
            throw new ProcessFailedException($process);
        }

        // Retornar el archivo como descarga
        return response()->download($backupPath)->deleteFileAfterSend(true);
    }
}


Si alguien pudiera ayudarme se los agradecería mucho, llevo días buscando la solución a que puede provocar eso pero no encuentro:(.

Según leo, tienes 2 errores durante el uso de mysql dump, al parecer hay comillas dobles (?) deja revisar.

Prueba dentro del process, del comando, poner el resultfile, de este modo -> "--result-file=$backupPath"

@Excorpion Hola, acabo de intentar pero sigue saliendo lo mismo:(
$process = new Process([
'C:\xampp\mysql\bin\mysqldump.exe',
'--user=' . env('DB_USERNAME'),
'--password=' . env('DB_PASSWORD'),
'--host=' . env('DB_HOST'),
env('DB_DATABASE'),
"--result-file=$backupPath",
]);
